# Anaconda - package in pkgs, not in site-packages

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to install tk package in Anaconda.  Using a work computer, which has admin blocks (which could be making this annoyingly hard).   In Anaconda, I see tk as an installed package, but when I try "import tk", it doesn't work:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-fb399ad622ad> in <module>()
----> 1 import tk

ImportError: No module named tk
```

I get the same error for import tk, import Tkinder, import tkinder.

Looking in site-packages/, tk isn't there.  I figure I have to install it, but I can't seem to figure out how.. whenever I try an install call, I think it tries to connect to the web, which is blocked.  I've tried:

```
conda install C:\[...]\pkgs\tk-8.5.18-vc9_0.tar.bz2
```

but get the following error:
CondaValueError: Value error:  cannot mix specifications with conda package filenames.

In cmd, trying conda install tk gives:
 [image]

Comment: 'when I try "import tk", it doesn't work.' Please provide more context as nobody can read your mind or see _how exactly_ it doesn't work for you.

Comment: No prob - fair comment.  I've made the edit and added the error when I try import

Comment: What if you try `import tkinter` or `import Tkinter`? Does that result in an error too?

Comment: Yup - same error..

Comment: I suppose it would help if I tried import Tkinter, not Tkinder......